# Importance of head tag in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a confusion, i gone through a page coding which written in jsp embedded the html, my task is to alter some HTML stuff.

In that i found there is end tag `</html>` but developer doesn't start the `<head>`.

But the page is working without any issues.

What i need to clarify is, is this type of approach always work? or is there any chances of issue occurrence?

Because i have to add coding to support the IE9 and coding regarding to implement the bootstrap

Comment: Modern browsers will render the page, even if it does not include all standard HTML elements. It is important to include the `<head>` tag, because it provides useful information, such as the page title, meta information, and stylesheets, etc. But a browser technically does not need the head tag to render the page.

Comment: Do realize that what a browser will do for you is different than what [the HTML spec for `<head>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) calls for. Under special circumstances, you don't need `<head>`, but under normal circumstances it is required.  If you let a browser do whatever it likes with a missing but required `<head>`, then you're relying on browser-specific behavior that may be different between vendors and could change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction, in HTML5, you don't need a `<head />` but you do need a `<title />` unless this HTML is for an iframe or something like an email:

> If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information
>   is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of
>   metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no
>   more than one is a base element. Otherwise: One or more elements of
>   metadata content, of which exactly one is a title element and no more
>   than one is a base element.

So it's not valid HTML, but browsers, for better or worse, let developers get away with a lot of crap. If you're supporting legacy browsers, things might get weird if you omit the head.

So both of the following are considered valid HTML5 documents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
</html>

<!-- Valid HTML5, but not valid HTML4 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Title</title>
</html>
```

You can check this with the [W3C's Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Here are the full specs about the omissions in HTML5:

> - An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
> - An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.
> - A head element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the head element is an element.
> - A head element's end tag may be omitted if the head element is not immediately followed by a space character or a comment.
> - A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character
>     or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a
>     script or style element.
> - A body element's end tag may be omitted if the body element is not immediately followed by a comment.

Comment: I am aware about the basic HTML elements, i had to alter file which was created by another developer, then i get this confusion. so clarifying it may good for me continue the work

Comment: You *might* get errors in some older browsers, so it would be wise to add it just in case. It's also never a good practice to have unkempt and erroneous code lying around in something that's used in production, especially if you consider yourself a professional.